# Anchor link to an input + make it checked state

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

I'm trying to make this anchor link, but upon clicking the input should instantly be added with the `:checked`. Is this possible without JS? So just pure CSS (the system where the HTML & CSS is placed in, is limited and doesn't like JS).

```css
.toggle:checked+h3+.collapsible-factuur-content {
        background-color: pink;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#details">Link to the anchor</a>

<div style="margin-top: 750px;">&nbsp;</div>


<div id="details">
    <mark>The anchor</mark>
</div>

<input class="toggle" id="collapsible-details-historiek" type="checkbox" data-hj-masked="">
<h3>
    <label class="gp-product" for="collapsible-details-historiek">
        <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
        <h4>Title of the item</h4>
    </label>
</h3>
<div class="collapsible-factuur-content" id="details-algemeen">
    Content of the item.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible without JavaScript. Unfortunately

The system doesn't like JavaScript a tiny bit...? Just so you can listen to the event

Update :

As you said maybe about the system taking JavaScript :

```html
<a href="#details" onclick="checkInput()">Link to the anchor</a>

<div style="margin-top: 750px;">&nbsp;</div>


<div id="details">
    <mark>The anchor</mark>
</div>

<input class="toggle" id="collapsible-details-historiek" type="checkbox" data-hj-masked="">
<h3>
    <label class="gp-product" for="collapsible-details-historiek">
        <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
        <h4>Title of the item</h4>
    </label>
</h3>
<div class="collapsible-factuur-content" id="details-algemeen">
    Content of the item.
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```js
function checkInput() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#collapsible-details-historiek');
  input.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it does, but not everything, what can I try?

Comment: I have updated the answer hopefully that works